# MySQL implementation of an iterator

Tags: sql, mysql, string

is it a way to implement an iterator in mysql which could return a column as 
"1/10"
"2/10"
...
"10/10"

Lets say the form is a/b, as input we have only b. Is it possible to solve this without procedure?

**EDIT**
An example. We have a relation PRINTS (id, work_id, edition_no) and EDITIONS (id, work_id, size, edition_size). For web-interface I am trying to render a select with possible options for prints. Html-options should look like

```
<option value="1">1/10</option>
<option value="2">2/10</option>
```

All my select list I render with SQL from database, but in this case I do not see any possibility to get it from database in way I need it. Sql should return 2 columns with option-value and option-text. That is a question.

Comment: Perhaps some example of what you would like to achieve? The way you describe it is not really clear.

Comment: SQL deals with the data -- looks like you need info on *presentation* of the data, which can be built into the query but really shouldn't be.  For PHP I'm assuming?

Comment: @OMG Ponies - Yes, I work with PHP. I know that in PHP it would not be a problem to make such iteration, it is not a question. The question was how would it look in Sql. Was it a reason to vote my question down?

Comment: Very well.  If you clarify for me what columns the values in 1/10 and 2/10 are coming from, I'll supply the query example.  I didn't downvote your question -- takes a lot for me to downvote someone, and that's only answers, never questions.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: The option-values are from <option value="prints.edition_no">prints.edition_no/editions.edition_size</option>. I need a query which would return 2 columns: prints.edition_no "prints.edition_no/editions.edition_size". In my example would look like: 1 1/10; 2 2/10, ..., 10 10/10

Answer (score 0):

SQL is all about relations, that is, tables. The natural way would be to create a one-column table with 10 (or however much you want) consecutive numbers, index it by that column, and `select` enough numbers from there, using `order by` and `limit`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [CONCAT function to concatenate strings in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
SELECT CONCAT('<option value="', p.edition_no, '">', p.edition_no. '/', e.edition_size, '</option>')
  FROM PRINTS p
  JOIN EDITIONS e ON e.work_id = p.work_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it is not what I am looking for. With your query I will get only 1 rowset, and I need all possible rowsets. The number of possible sets is defined by edition_size. If the edition_size is 5 we should get 5 rows.

Comment: @Anatoliy: I think you misread CONCAT for GROUP_CONCAT -- this will return a row for however many are joined.  I was unclear on what to join between the tables, but I suggest you test the query or provide data for me to confirm your findings (others are likely to have the same issue).